# UITextView, in UITableViewCell with autoLayout in iOS 7+

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uitextview, nsattributedstring

Allright, I think I've read all the issues which seemed to be the same as I did.

I have a UITextView in a UITableViewCell, the cell itself contains an imageView, a UILabel as title, the UITextView and another UILabel.

Screenshot:
[image]

I believe the constraints to be correct. Currently the view does an estimate which is correct in most cases, but in my case the content is larger than the UITableViewCell's height, this is probably due to the delayed rendering of the UITableViewCell, causing other list items to draw behind this one (it only appears on top).

The code which estimates the height:

```
func heightForCellAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if (calculatorCell[cellIdentifier] == nil) {
            calculatorCell[cellIdentifier] = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell
        }

        if let cell = calculatorCell[cellIdentifier] {
            populateCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)

            cell.setNeedsLayout()
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()

            return cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        }
        ErrorClass.log("Could not instantiate cell? returning 100 float value instead for listView")
        return 100.0
    }
```

This is a generic function as you see since it's handling a UITableViewCell not a custom, so the populateCell in this case, the first index returns the cell with the issue, the rest are comments which are working fine, I'm just sharing it all since people will ask for it:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        let cellUnwrapped = cell as! ChallengeHeader

        cellUnwrapped.setContent(
            challenge!.content,
            date: StrFormat.deadLineFromDate(challenge!.endAt),
            likes: Language.countValue("challenge_count_like", count: challenge!.totalLikes),
            likeController: self,
            commentCount: Language.countValue("global_count_comment", count: challenge!.totalComments)
        )

        cellUnwrapped.like(userLiked)

        cellUnwrapped.loadAttachments(challenge!.attachments)

        return cellUnwrapped
    } else {
        let cellUnwrapped = cell as! ListItemComment
        let challengeComment = items[(indexPath.row - 1)] as! ChallengeComment
        var username = "Anonymous"
        if let user = challengeComment.author as User? {
            cellUnwrapped.iconLoad(user.avatar)
            username = user.displayName
        }

        cellUnwrapped.setContentValues(
            StrFormat.cleanHtml(challengeComment.text),
            date: StrFormat.dateToShort(challengeComment.createdAt),
            username: username
        )

        return cellUnwrapped
}
```

The cell's setContentvalues which parses the html string to NSAttributedString, it's wrapped in an if to prevent reloads to re-render the NSAttributedString. It won't change but it does take a while to render:

```
func setContent(content:String, date:String, likes:String, likeController : LikeController, commentCount:String) {
    if (content != txtContent) {
        self.contentLabel.text = nil
        self.contentLabel.font = nil
        self.contentLabel.textColor = nil
        self.contentLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        contentLabel.attributedText = StrFormat.fromHtml(content)
        txtContent = content
    }
    deadlineLabel.text = date
    likesLabel.text = likes
    self.likeController = likeController
    likeButton.addTarget(self, action: "likeClicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    totalComments.text = commentCount
    totalComments.textColor = StyleClass.getColor("primaryColor")
    doLikeLayout()
}
```

So TL;DR; I have a UITextView inside a UITableViewCell scaling sizes using autolayout and containing an NSAttributedString to parse html and html links. How come it does not render well, and how to fix it?

Comment: It could be because when you create a prototype cell using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, the cell is not part of the table so has no size class. I found that I had to add the cell to the table using `[self.tableView addSubview:cell]`, do the sizing, then remove it using `[cell removeFromSuperview]`. This gives it a size class for a short period it can use to size properly. If labels are multiline you also need to set preferredMaxLayoutWidth on the UILabels.

Comment: Sounded like a good idea but it only got worse when I tried it. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Most examples I have seen use UILayoutFittingCompressedSize rather than UILayoutFittingExpandedSize. May be worth a try.

Comment: Oh sorry, My example I tried Fitting, it was and now yet again is Compressed. It seems to work better in most cases.